# Low Level Calls in Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix

I am a beginner to solidity and I came across this concept called "Low-Level Calls". What exactly is a Low-level function? and How is it different from others?

Answer (score 6):

In Solidity, the `address` object has a method named `call()` through which you can call every function you want, and if the address implements it, it will be triggered.

For example:

```
contract SomeContract {
    function any() public {
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("myFunction(uint,address)", 10, msg.sender);
        // if success is `true` the function exists and it had returned some result
        (uint a, uint b) = abi.decode(result, (uint, uint)); // This is an example of how the result might have been decoded
    }
}
```

You can also use this syntax:

```
address.call.gas(50000).value(1 ether)(data);
```

Here, you forward some ETH and gas. The variable `data` is something like this:

```
0x38ed1739000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000127126c0ab345650000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000012a8ef05e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a00000000000000000000000000e1751fb76a2f4a8288c0af347def0d5fd5313a7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006168497f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000007ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f6190000000000000000000000002791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174
```

The first 4 bytes after the `0x` symbol represent the function signature - the first 4 bytes of the function signature after encoding it with the keccak256 hash function. In this case, it is the first 4 bytes of

```
abi.keccak256("swapExactTokensForTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)")
```

Everything after that is the representation of the calldata which will be parsed as the function arguments.

Comment: What is this syntax? `owner.call{value: amount}('');`

Comment: Some of the new solidity version introduced it. https://solidity-by-example.org/call/

Answer (score -1):

Low level interactions are used to send funds or calldata or funds & calldata to a contract through the receive() or fallback() function.

Examples of low level functions are call and delegate call.

The difference between low level functions to a regular solidity function is that low level functions only works when fallback/receive are implemented.

Also when a call is being made from a low level function to a regular function, we display "transact to ... (fallback)" instead of writing the name of the function.

For in-depth info check out
https://medium.com/remix-ide/low-level-interactions-on-remix-ide-5f79b05ac86

Comment: Low level interactions can do anything high level interactions can do, and more besides. A low level call can call any externally visible function.